# How to get difference between two timestamps in days, that works on Postgres AND H2?

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2, database-migration

How do you compare two timestamps in a way that works on Postgres as well as H2?
Migrating from MySQL/H2 to Postgres/H2 I had this

MySQL/H2

```
MAX(TIMESTAMPDIFF(DAY, person.enrolled, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP())) AS daysSinceEnrolled
```

changed into

Postgres/H2

```
FLOOR(MAX((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - person.enrolled))/3600/24)) AS daysSinceEnrolled
```

However EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ...) doesn't work in H2..
So what is the way to get the same results as before?

Comment: Why not just work with the `interval` returned from `current_timestamp - person.enrolled`?

Comment: PostgreSQL-style `EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM interval)` works in H2 too, perhaps you're using some old version of H2 without that feature.

Comment: I've update H2 to the latest version, as well as hibernate with that and am still seeing the same issue I'm afraid. Is there anything I can do to verify that it works with the current H2 version? Other than seeing it fail as it is now.. @evgenij-ryazanov

Comment: Expression with `EXTRACT` from your question definitely works since H2 1.4.198 Beta (don't use that outdated buggy version) and in all later versions. I mean it works in pure SQL queries, I didn't test JPQL/HQL, it is a different story.